# Drawing a line with a gradient color in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I found this question for different technologies but not using OpenCV in c++. I need to draw a line that changes its color in order to represent direction One color where it starts and another where it finishes, so visually I can see the direction of several trajectories I have. each trajectory has several points, but not the same amount.

Comment: Can't you just use an [arrow](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga0a165a3ca093fd488ac709fdf10c05b2)?

Comment: @Miki that's pretty cool, didn't even know that existed in OpenCV.

Comment: @miki there is too many trajectories, that it will not provide much help in the visualization.

Comment: Maybe you can show a few images so we can get a better idea

Comment: Here's how to draw a line, so you could draw it and calculate the percentage of your distance from line start to line end at each point and use that to determine the appropriate colour for the point... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm

Comment: Or, create a simple straight, horizontal line of varying colour on a piece of spare canvas (i.e. a Mat) at the start of your program. Then, each time you want to plot a line, clone your original line, resize it to the correct length, rotate it and copy it to the origin of your desired line.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want different colors for each direction? What i would do is i would pick a reference line like horizontal one. And calculate angle between each line and the horizontal line. Then i would map 255 value to 360 degree for example color=255/360*angleFound. Then put this value to cv::line function. cv::line(  ,  ,  RGB(color,color,color)). This is an example. You can put this color value in different ways. In this way each direction would have its own color.